# Variable Assignment TensorFlow Sizing Error

Tags: tensorflow

Both are scalars. I'm trying to reassign the variable. But I'm unable to because every iteration changes the size of the variable. I tried all kinds of transformations but they do not work. Any idea?

I'm trying to just have a behaviour like appending an element to a list.

```
a = tf.Variable(0.00, tf.float32)
b = tf.Variable(0.00, tf.float32)
a.assign(tf.pack([a, b]))
```

This gives an error:

```
ValueError: Shapes () and (2,) are not compatible
```

Comment: The types differ, so that won't work. Although the code is Python, TF graphs check the types. How about using a third variable, that would host the result of `tf.pack([a, b])`?

Comment: But my variable would always be increasing by one at every iteration. It means I've to create thousands of variables to accommodate the increasing dimensions.

Comment: I don't have any context to think about it much. The [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#Variable) states: "The initial value defines the type and shape of the variable. After construction, the type and shape of the variable are fixed." This means that an assignment to `a` must provide a float value. How about working on a dynamic structure (it is more complex than a list) "later", for example with a `TensorArray`, tensors and APIs such as `tf.expand_dims`?

Answer (score 0):

`a` is a single scalar variable
`b` is a single scalar variable

you can only assign other *single* scalar values to these variables (is not like python that you can assign anything).

when you do `tf.pack([a, b])` you are creating a tensor, and you cannot assign a tensor to a single scalar variable. You have to create a new Variable.